# Changing the layout of individual item for listview or recyclerview

Tags: android, listview, imageview, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I am trying to make a recyclerview or listview. The complication I have is that some of the items I want to display are images with text and some are videos. I was thinking that I could put the videoview and the imageviews on the same list item xml layout and hide programatically. I can do the list of video views and the list of images with text but when it comes to doing both depending on what the user selects I am unsure where to start.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just put together a quick example because I was curious on what is the best way to achieve this the most efficient way possible. This is what I put together to achieve inflating different views.

I am using a RecyclerView and inflating the list items based on what I am setting in the model.  For this example, I am using setPos() and getPos().  If it is an image I setPos() to 0 and 1 for video. Then within the getItemViewType, I check to see if the getPos() is a 0 or 1.  If it is 0, it inflates ViewHolderImage and if it is 0, it inflates ViewHolderVideo. Hope this helps.

Here is what this simple recycler looks like.

[image]

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Items> items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Items().setItems("IMAGE", 0));
        items.add(new Items().setItems("VIDEO", 1));
        items.add(new Items().setItems("IMAGE", 0));
        items.add(new Items().setItems("IMAGE", 0));
        items.add(new Items().setItems("VIDEO", 1));
        RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        ExampleRecyclerAdapter exampleRecyclerAdapter = new ExampleRecyclerAdapter(items);
        recycler.setAdapter(exampleRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    // Model
    public class Items {
        String item;
        int pos;
        // 0 = image
        // 1 = video

        public Items setItems(String item, int pos) {
            Items newItem = new Items();
            newItem.setItem(item);
            newItem.setPos(pos);
            return newItem;
        }

        public String getItem() {
            return item;
        }

        public void setItem(String item) {
            this.item = item;
        }

        public int getPos() {
            return pos;
        }

        public void setPos(int pos) {
            this.pos = pos;
        }
    }


    // RecyclerAdapter
    public class ExampleRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private static final int VIEW_HOLDER_IMAGE = 0;
        private static final int VIEW_HOLDER_VIDEO = 1;

        private List<Items> listItem;

        public ExampleRecyclerAdapter(List<Items> listItem) {
            this.listItem = listItem;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (listItem.get(position).getPos() == 0) {
                return VIEW_HOLDER_IMAGE;
            } else {
                return VIEW_HOLDER_VIDEO;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            switch (viewType) {
                case VIEW_HOLDER_IMAGE:
                    return new ViewHolderImage(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_image, parent, false));
                case VIEW_HOLDER_VIDEO:
                    return new ViewHolderVideo(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_video, parent, false));
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder v, int pos) {
            if (v instanceof ViewHolderImage) { // Handle Image Layout
                ViewHolderImage viewHolderImage = (ViewHolderImage) v;
                viewHolderImage.textView.setText(String.format("%s %d", listItem.get(pos).getItem(), listItem.get(pos).getPos()));
                viewHolderImage.itemView.setTag(viewHolderImage);
            } else if (v instanceof ViewHolderVideo) { // Handle Video Layout
                ViewHolderVideo viewHolderVideo = (ViewHolderVideo) v;
                viewHolderVideo.textView.setText(String.format("%s %d", listItem.get(pos).getItem(), listItem.get(pos).getPos()));
                viewHolderVideo.itemView.setTag(viewHolderVideo);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return listItem.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolderImage extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private TextView textView;

            public ViewHolderImage(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_textView);
            }
        }

        public class ViewHolderVideo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private TextView textView;

            public ViewHolderVideo(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_textView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="transfast.com.teststuff.Main2Activity" />
```

recycler_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

recycler_video.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```